# How to manage different sections of the application with Angular 2

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular2-routing

I'm using [this template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnetcore-spa) and would like to separate my application using ASP.NET Areas. Let's say there a website that has a public area and an admin area. Right now I can display the home area just fine but I don't know how to change the base layout for example for displaying the admin area (which is supposed to be completely different than the public area).

From what I understand I need to use Angular **Components** and create one for public page and another for admin page and connect them together in the `app` component but not sure how they would work **together** so that the `/admin/**` route is redirected to the **corresponding component**.(That has it's own base layout) Any code example would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use routes to do this? With angular 2 router you can make nested navigation. You'd have an huge area with rough layout (company logo etc) and an router-outlet and 2 routes one for "" (empty, which will be used as default) and one for "admin". This load the overall layout, with each of them having their own router-outlets, which load the first/default page

Comment: @Tseng Would you mind providing a code example?

Comment: @VSG24   Did you get it figured out?

Comment: @Christopher After wasting about 4 month trying to "get started" with `Angular 2` I ended up dumping it for good. I'm now using `Vue.js` and so far I'm extremely pleased.

Comment: @VSG24  Sorry, to hear that! I've recently begun to look at Vue.js too. I hear great things about it!!

Hopefully, my answer will be able to help someone else in the future so they don't have to waste time! 

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that template, but with Angular you can set up nested routes and do something like this:

```
// app.routing.ts

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: PublicComponent,
          children: [
            { path: "", component: HomeComponent },
            { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
            { path: "join", component: JoinComponent },
            { path: “login/forgot-your-password", component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
          ]
  },
  { path: "admin", component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AdminGuard],
          children: [
            { path: “users", component: UsersListComponent },
            { path: “secret", component: SecretComponent, canActivate: [SecretGuard] },
            { path: “message", component: MessageComponent }
          ]
    }
];
```

---

```
// app.component.html

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

---

```
// public.component.html

<header>
      <app-header></app-header>
</header>

<main>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>

<footer>
      <app-footer></app-footer>
</footer>
```

---

```
// admin.component.html

<header>
      <app-admin-header></app-admin-header>
</header>

<main>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

And you can nest even further if an already nested path needs to have children as well.